# How to read local files using Guzzle http

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, guzzle6

I am trying to load this using GuzzleHTTP `file://localhost/`.
It shows `libcurl 'file://' protocol not supported`.
How can I fix this, please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No way to read local file with Guzzle. It's said that the protocol not supported. Use something like file_get_contents instead.